# Regular expression for street address regardless of order (either /<house> <street>/ or /<street> <house>/)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse a street address into the street name and the house number, but I want to allow the house number to appear either before or after the street name. The following code yields a syntax error:

```js
const { groups: { house, street } } = streetAddress.match(/^(?<house>\d+)\s+(?<street>.*)|(?<street>.*)\s+(?<house>\d+)$/);
```

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?<house>\d+)\s+(?<street>.*)|(?<street>.*)\s+(?<house>\d+)$/: Duplicate capture group name
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: is this not valid XML? Seems like using a parser would be better if it is.

Comment: What does the actual strings look like for testing our solutions?

Comment: In JavaScript, you can't do that in the "elegant" way. Use two separate regexps.

Comment: For example: "20592 Donnelly Lights" and "Zeitlin 9".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution, which I think is reasonably elegant:

```js
const { groups: { house, street } } =
    streetAddress.match(/^(?<house>\d+)\s+(?<street>.*)$/) || 
    streetAddress.match(/^(?<street>.*)\s+(?<house>\d+)$/);
```

(It probably needs to be wrapped in a `try` block to deal with addresses that don't match either pattern.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to do this with named capture groups. I know, logically the group names are not duplicated because there is an OR there. But that would require a semantic analysis of the regex by the parser, and parsers really shouldn't go that deep in their initial analysis. In fact, if they did, you could use a regex parser as a SAT solver, which would imply that parsing a regex would be NP-hard in worst case.

But enough of the digression, this instead works:

```js
const streetAddress = process.argv[2];
const groups = streetAddress.match(/^(\d+)\s+(.*)|(.*)\s+(\d+)$/);
const house = groups[1] || groups[4];
const street = groups[2] || groups[3];
console.log({house, street});
```

Examples:

```
> node x.js "1234 Mongomery"
{ house: '1234', street: 'Mongomery' }

> node x.js "Neuer Weg 1234"
{ house: '1234', street: 'Neuer Weg' }
```